# Kotlin Android Studio Recyclerview does not recycle

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i just do some beginner things and i followed a simple tutorial to create a Recycler View in Android Studio, launched it on Pixel 5 API 24
It works almost perfectly, i implemented it with a string-array in strings.xml. But the main problem is that actually the recycle function doesn't work. If i launch my program, recyclerview populate all 17 items, but if i scroll down to last items, it doesn't recycle all the list and restart with item 0
I cant exmplain this, i followed the guide step-by-step... thanks for the patience.
Here is the files:

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon_background">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***card_view.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/quest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FBEFCA"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/craftsman" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:textSize="32dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Craftsman" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                android:text="Oh ohh ohhh! Pick that armour! You sould at least 100 items at craftsman." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/description"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
                android:text="Unlocked"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.kt***

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val data = ArrayList<ItemsViewModel>()
        val icons: IntArray = intArrayOf(R.drawable.craftsman, R.drawable.building, R.drawable.crown, R.drawable.excalibur, R.drawable.gold_boots, R.drawable.gold_cup, R.drawable.helmet,
        R.drawable.horse, R.drawable.knight, R.drawable.ring_temple, R.drawable.lord, R.drawable.secret_quest, R.drawable.sword_man, R.drawable.touch, R.drawable.wizard, R.drawable.tourch, R.drawable.workwoman)
        val titles = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_title)
        val descriptions = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_description)
        val locks = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_lock)


        for (i in 0..16) {
            data.add(ItemsViewModel(icons[i], titles[i],descriptions[i], locks[i]))
        }

        val adapter = CustomAdapter(data)
        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

}
```

***CustomAdapter.kt***

```
class CustomAdapter(private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(binding: CardViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val icon = binding.icon
        val description = binding.description
        val lock = binding.lock
        val title = binding.title
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = CardViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,
                                                                false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val ItemsViewModel = mList[position]

        holder.icon.setImageResource(ItemsViewModel.icon)
        holder.title.text = ItemsViewModel.title
        holder.description.text = ItemsViewModel.description
        holder.lock.text = ItemsViewModel.lock
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to elaborate on your issue because it's not clear what's the problem, maybe include a screenshot if you have issue describing it. I don't see anything that'd misbehave in those code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Recycling means it will create only number of item-views (cardview items in your case) which can be displayed on the screen and on scrolling, for example on scrolling-up, the item-view which will be hidden off the screen upside, the same view will be reused with updated data for the new entering item from downside. This you can observe by putting a log statement in onCreateViewHolder method. It will create only approx number of viewholders that would cover the screen, and will reuse the same. E.g. if 8 items will cover the screen, it can create approx 10 viewholders and reuse them for displaying entire list irrespective of size.

In your case, what do you mean by not recycling?